# How to implement routing in swift based on protocols

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to implement routing in `Swift` like `ReactJS`, I have implemented protocols to serve for Routing.

But it's getting crashed in `UIViewController` extention. Can anyone help me with the solution.

Here is my code.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func presented(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("\(#function)")
        present(Route.destination, animated: animated,
                completion: nil)
    }

    func pushed(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("\(#function)")
        _ = navigationController?.pushViewController(Route.destination,
                                                     animated: true)
    }
}

protocol Router {
    static func toController <T: UIViewController>(_ controller:T,
                                                   params: Any) -> T
}

class Route : Router {
    static var destination: UIViewController!

    static func toController<T:UIViewController>(_ controller: T,
                                                 params: Any) -> T {
        let viewController : T = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: T.self)) as! T

        destination = viewController
        return viewController
    }
}



class ViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBAction func navigate() {
            Route.toController(SecondViewControlller(), params: [])
                .presented(true)
      }
}
```

Comment: is Route.destination set?

Comment: yes, You can see in this line         destination = viewController

Comment: there is a possibility that SecondViewControlller() got deallocated as there was no strong reference to it.

Comment: You are presenting the viewController on itself in **present** method in UIViewController extension. Make sure that it has to be different from the one which has to be presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app is crashing because you are going to present the same
>   viewController on itself.

The reason is below method takes destination viewController as an argument and return itself as destination.

```
static func toController <T: UIViewController>(_ controller:T, params: Any) -> T
```

In addition to that, whenever `presented(_ animated: Bool)` gets called from `Route.toController(SecondViewControlller(), params: []).presented(true)`,  `self` and `Route.destination` are same. So, it leads to presenting the same viewController on itself and causing sort of below error or crashing the application.

> Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

Try this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presented(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("\(#function)")
        self.present(Route.destination, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }

    func pushed(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("\(#function)")
        _ = self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Route.destination, animated: true)
    }
}

protocol Router {
    static func toController <T: UIViewController, T2: UIViewController>(_ controller: T2, from source: T, params: Any) -> T
}

class Route : Router {
    static var destination: UIViewController!

    static func toController <T: UIViewController, T2: UIViewController>(_ controller: T2, from source: T, params: Any) -> T {
        let viewController : T2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: T2.self)) as! T2

        destination = viewController
        return source
    }
}

//Your ViewController.swift
@IBAction func onButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {

    Route.toController(SecondViewControlller(), from: self, params: []).presented(true)
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you 